# Solve for a variable with a variable exponent.

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function, exponentiation

I'm working on a video-game and have come up with the following equation:

$$B^S={B-1\over R} +1$$

I need to solve for B in terms of R and S (which will be supplied at runtime) but for the life of me I can't seem to simplify it. I even tried an online variable solver and it just gives up.

Conceptually grasping what this is supposed to contribute to convinces me there has to be a solution, I'm hoping somebody has the knowledge to arrive at it. For what it's worth, the intended values for R are in the 0 < R < 1 range, and S is intended to be in the 1 <= S <= 2 range.

Much gratitude!

EDIT:
In the end I found a different approach for my application which yielded a general solution. Thank you all who contributed, it did help!

Comment: 0 > R < 1 means $R < 1$ and $R<0$ and hence $R < 0$. I guess this is not what you meant...

Comment: Are $R$ and $S$ constants?

Comment: @amsmath *They will be supplied at runtime*: so no, they can vary.

Comment: After doing some rearrangements, you're left with $B^S+(-1/R)B+(1/R-1)=0$, which is an $S^\text{th}$ degree equation in $B$. Unless someone uses the ranges you provided to  come up with some neat approximations, I'm afraid there's no general solution for these.

Comment: I guess that you can only write down an explicit solution for special values of $S$ such as $1$, $2$, or $3/2$. You should solve this using Newton's method.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder - since $S$ is in the range $[1,2]$ this is unlikely to be a polynomial.

Comment: @amsmath good catch on those comparisons, you are correct.

Comment: @Mr. Xcoder - you are correct, R and S are not constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except for very few specific cases, you cannot get explicit solutions and you need numerical methods.

Consider that you look for the zero(s) of function
$$f(B)=B^S-\frac{B-1}{R}-1$$
$$f'(B)=S B^{S-1}-\frac{1}{R}$$
$$f''(B)=(S-1) S B^{S-2}$$
The first derivative cancels at a point
$$B_*=\left(\frac{1}{R S}\right)^{\frac{1}{S-1}}$$ and the second derivative is always positive if $ 1 < S <2$ (I do not consider the cases $S=1$ or $S=2$ for which the problem is simple). Since we can bound the function, the solution is always between $\left(\frac 1R -1\right)$ and $1$.

You can also notice that $B=1$ is a trivial solution for any $R,S$ in the provided ranges. Since $f(0)=\frac 1R >0$, if $f(B_*) <0$, then the solution is $> B_*$.

So, what I should do is to compute $f(k B_*)$ for $k=2,3,4,\cdots$ until we find the smallest $k$ such that $f(k B_*)>0$. At this point, let $B_0=k_{min}B_*$ and start Newton method.

Let us take one example using $S=1.234$ and $R=0.567$; this gives $B_*\approx 4.6$. Using the simplistic procedure, we find $k_{min}=2$; so start using $B_0=9.2$ and get the following iterates
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & B_n \\
 0 & 9.201489213 \\
 1 & 9.194700041 \\
 2 & 9.194696121
\end{array}
\right)$$

Let us repeat using  $S=1.357$ and $R=0.246$; this gives $B_*\approx 21.6$. Using the simplistic procedure, we find $k_{min}=3$; so start using $B_0=64.8$ and get the following iterates
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & B_n \\
 0 & 64.83555879 \\
 1 & 51.00444906 \\
 2 & 48.72198422 \\
 3 & 48.64769013 \\
 4 & 48.64760965
\end{array}
\right)$$

If you want something more sophisticated, we could approximate $B_0$ expanding the function as a truncated Taylor series around $B_*$. This would give
$$B_0=B_*+ \sqrt{-2\frac{f(B_*) }{f''(B_*) }}$$ For the worked examples, this would give as starting values $8.76$ and $46.05$.

Comment: This does seem like the overall more complete approach - many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Rearrange your equation to
$$ B=f(B)=\sqrt[S]{\frac{B-1}R+1}$$

You could start with a rough estimate then apply the function $f(B)$ several times until the answer settles down.
$$\begin{split}
B_1&=2\\
B_2&=f(B_1)\\
B_3&=f(B_2)\\
B_4&=f(B_3)\\
B_5&=f(B_4)\\
&\hspace{0.55em}\vdots
\end{split}$$
You might check first that $S$ isn't exactly 1 or 2.  There is no solution when $S=1$ and a simple solution when $S=2$.

EDIT

Sorry, ,Newton's method would be

$$B_2=B_1-\frac{RB_1^S-R-B_1+1}{RSB_1^{S-1}-1}$$
and repeat for B3, and so on.

Comment: If $S=1$, then $B=1$ is a solution and, if in addition $R=1$, then each real number is a solution.

Comment: This would be Newton's method, yes? It checks out but unfortunately can end up requiring too many iterations to approximate a decent result for my purposes. But I'll accept this as the answer as it seems there's no general solution as I had hoped. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure this answer works? This solution doesn't work out for a simpler function $x=f(x)=\frac{1}{2}(x^2+1)$ where you should get the answer $x=1$.

Comment: @user496634 when $r=1/2,S=2$ it turns   into $B-\frac12(B-1)$ which does converge on 1.  The method, to solve $g(B)=0$, does $B - g(B)/g '(B)$

Comment: The first method only works if the derivative of $f(B)$ is below 1.  So you have to arrange that, here by doing $sqrt(2x-1)$ instead of $(x^2+1)/2$.  Since the derivative eqals 1, the method is right on the edge of working for your example.

Comment: Indeed. I missed out the range given in the OP's question, you are right.